# Div's not aligning next to each other

Tags: html, css, alignment

For some reason, these two divs are not aligning next to each other, I was wondering if anyone would be able to help?

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/aaronmtx/pen/qNZoBK), if anyone can help.

```css
/*------------------Portfolio(start)------------------*/

.portfolio {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  padding-bottom: 55%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.portfolio h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-top: 5%;
  color: #212121;
  font-size: 2.4em;
}
.portfolio-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* port-left-text */

.port-left-text {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.port-left-text h1 {
  text-align: left;
}
.port-left-text h3 {
  font-weight: 300;
}
.port-left-text p {
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
/* portfolio-right-display */

.portfolio-right-display {
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.portfolio-right-display img {
  width: 65%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.portfolio-right-display img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <h1>Portfolio</h1>

  <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
    <div class="port-left-text">
      <h1>Project Title</h1>
      <h3>Project type</h3>

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries,</p>
    </div>

    <div class="portfolio-right-display">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://feelgrafix.com/data/background/background-15.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: margin is a part of 100% width, you got 110%

Comment: Works now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Margin adds up in the width procentage. To make it reach 100% exactly so both `divs` stay on the same row you need add up the margin.

For example in your code you could change the width from `50%` to `45%` like this.

```
.portfolio-right-display {
    width: 45%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.port-left-text {
    width: 45%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This make it 45 + 45 + 5 + 5 which is a 100. Before my change it was 50 + 50 + 5 + 5 which is 110.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your combined widths including the 5% margin exceed 100%.  Set the widths to 45%, and they display side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Remove/Comment the margin from both of the following classes:

```
.port-left-text {
/*padding-top: 5%; */
}
.portfolio-right-display {
width: 50%;
/*  margin-right: 5%; */
}
```

You have given width of 50% with additional margin of 5% to each of the element which is greater than 100% width. Either remove the margins or reduce the elements width.